# Minted ` \begin{minted}{...}` KO but `\inputminted` OK

Tags: minted, fancyvrb, pygments

Since a few days I can't color anymore python code with `minted`; I don't have any error message in the log file, only the minted output doesn't appear in the pdf file.

On the other hand, everything works strangely well with the command `\inputminted`. How to fix this?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
ABCDE
\begin{minted}{python}
def __init__(self, x, y): 
    self.x=x
    self.y=y
\end{minted}
% \inputminted ... work's 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course your code doesn't produce a black background with white letters. I get the expected result from the code you posted.

Comment: I can produce an output without the dark mode of my editor. The issue is the same.

Comment: Oh, well, I updated `fancyvrb` and I see the issue. Too bad! Time to downgrade.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update (27 November 2021):** This issue is now fixed in `fancyvrb` 4.1. In version 4.0, `fancyvrb` changed the handling of the `lastline` option so that using `lastline=` hides all lines (nothing is displayed). However, this also caused `lastline` used with no argument to hide all lines. That is, the `lastline` default was to hide all lines. `minted` uses `lastline` (default argument) as part of the highlighting process for `minted` environments, so these environments stopped displaying anything with `fancyvrb` 4.0.  Everything works correctly again with `fancyvrb` 4.1, which switches `lastline` (default argument) back to the original behavior.

---

The relevant change seems to be `\@ne` -> `\z@` on `fancyvrb.sty` line 225.  This causes `minted` to write nothing to the temp file it uses for highlighting code, instead of writing the code.

Everything can be switched back to the original behavior, fixing `minted`, by adding this to the preamble:

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\FV@DefineFindStop{%
  \ifx\FancyVerbStopString\relax
    \ifnum\FancyVerbStopNum<\@ne
      \let\FV@FindStartStop\FV@@PreProcessLine
    \else
      \let\FV@FindStartStop\FV@FindStopNum
    \fi
  \else
    \let\FV@FindStartStop\FV@FindStopString
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

At this point (22 November 2021), I am still unsure whether this change in `fancyvrb` was fixing an old bug (in which case `minted` should adapt), introducing a new bug, or defining new behavior.

Comment: the change is meant to introduce a new feature, there was a request to be able to suppress a verbatim environment completly, and the update says ` added lastline=0 for no output`, but this killed the (documented) `lastline` behaviour without argument, to get everything you have to use `lastline=-1` now. This should really be reported to fancyvrb.

Comment: It seems that with `fancyvrb` 4.1 the `autogobble` option of `minted` does not work anymore. (Since the `minted` library of `tcolorbox` has `autogobble` as default, I'm receiving bug reports for listings with `tcolorbox` caused by this change). I do not know if `autogobble` or `fancyvrb` needs to be adapted.

Comment: Just looking into the `minted` code, I read `\ifx\FancyVerbStartNum\z@` for `autogobble` which may/should (?) be replaced by `\ifx\FancyVerbStartNum\m@ne` for `fancyvrb` 4.1a

Comment: Not working again in 4.1b

Comment: @ManuelAlves It's working fine for me. If you can't get it figured out, I'd suggest creating a new question with an example document that reproduces whatever issue you are seeing.

Comment: @G.Poore Thanks, I've just done that (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632891/beginmintedpython-not-showing-in-pdf). Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

It is a bug/a change in the newest fancyvrb. The following prints everything with the older version but suppress the line with the newest:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[lastline=]
blub
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

You should report this.

Comment: Haaaaaaa, thanks ! how to waste half a day to find a solution, for nothing  :- )

Comment: I'm not sure who should adapt, perhaps minted should. But ask the maintainer of fancyvrb first.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\makeatletter
\def\KV@FV@lastline@default{%
  \let\FancyVerbStopNum\m@ne
  \let\FancyVerbStopString\relax}
\fvset{lastline}
\makeatother
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
ABCDE
\begin{minted}{python}
def __init__(self, x, y): 
    self.x=x
    self.y=y
\end{minted}
blub

\begin{Verbatim}
abc
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

I'll fix it and upload it to CTAN